# create react app in an already existing project that was made using create react app

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have an existing project that was made using create react app and i want to make a new test folder using create react app so it will have a package.json file inside it that will configure a jest/enzyme test suite. Is this possible and will the test suite take the local package.json and node_modules. Is this legal to do and will it let me customize the package.json file for the test suite only?

Comment: You can do it, but why not just create the test suite in the current CRA?

Comment: when i did that i got an error that said that i had the wrong version of babel, it requires 7.0.0 and the project already had 6.23.3 and no matter how many times i upgraded babel it gave me the same error. It seems like the project has a step in the build where it uses 6.23.3 babel and my tests arent compatible with it. I decided to create my own package.json inside my testing suite so i can at least run the tests. i am not sure if thats bad practice or not but i think it will work if i can configure the new package.json to just run jest and enzyme testing.